# Xamarin Forms binding collection of strings c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to bind a collection of string to a listiview that contains elements with these strings, but I don't know how to do this:

```
name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ??? );
```

I know that in the xaml I can do this

```
<Label Text="{Binding }"/>
```

but what's the equivalent in codebehind?
I need customcell because the listitem has also other elements

ViewModel:

```
private BindableCollection<string> _wifiNetworks;
    public BindableCollection<string> WifiNetworks
    {
        get { return _wifiNetworks; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _wifiNetworks)
            {
                _wifiNetworks = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WifiNetworks);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the View:

```
   var wifiList = new ListView
        {
             RowHeight = 50
        };
        wifiList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("WifiNetworks"));
        wifiList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
```

CustomCell.cs:

```
public CustomCell()
    {                          

        var name = new Label
        {
            TextColor= (Color)Application.Current.Resources["ForegroundColor"],
            FontSize = 17               
        };

        name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ??? );

    }
```

Comment: You should have a look on this https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%3CT%3E/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/ this

Comment: `String` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Does that suite you ?

Answer (score 3):

The "." binding path will bind a property directly to the BindingContext

```
name.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "." );
```